# searching the specific value in nested object and returning the updated original object ith only searched item using javascript

Tags: javascript

searching the specific value in nested object and returning the updated original object with only searched item using javascript

```
 var people= {
      "i": [
        {
          "country": "Australia",
          "list": [
            {
              "name": "ABC   ",
              "address": "AB street ",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "country": "Brazil",
          "list": [
            {
              "name": "XZ   ",
              "address": "AB street "
            },
           ...
          ]
        }
      ]
     ...
    };
```

I want to search by name.

Answer (score 1):

Using function `Object.keys()` and breaking the deepest loop when a `key === searchedText`.

```js
var pages = {  "1": [{    "title": "Australia",    "list": [{        "key": "Base1",        "label": "Base-label",        "description": "description"      },      {        "key": "Base1",        "label": "Base-label",        "description": "description"      }    ]  }],  "2": [{      "title": "Australia",      "list": [{          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        }      ]    },    {      "title": "Netherlands",      "list": [{          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base2",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        }      ]    }  ],  "3": [{      "title": "Usa",      "list": [{          "key": "Base2",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        }      ]    },    {      "title": "Canada",      "list": [{          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base1",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        },        {          "key": "Base2",          "label": "Base-label",          "description": "description"        }      ]    }  ]};

var filteredPages = {};
var searchedText = "Base2";
for (var k of Object.keys(pages)) {
  for (var o of pages[k]) {
    for (var io of o.list) {
      if (io.key.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) !== -1)  {
        filteredPages[k] = filteredPages[k] || [];
        filteredPages[k].push({
          title: o.title,
          list: [io]
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(filteredPages)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ele, Thanks for the code but it is not working as you have taken var pages = output .

Comment: @nim you don't need to map because you want to filter rather than converting those objects.

Comment: Hi, if I want to merge the object property - list of SAME TITLE lying on same page. How can I do it? Input and output has been updated.